# Execute multiple statements before releasing connection oracledb module node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

UPDATE: code updated below (6-20-2016). I am still having trouble with having the async waterfall to finish, but when I add my callback to the function(err) part of .forEachOf function, it still gives me the error.

I am trying to run multiple insert statements to insert each value from two arrays to an oracle database using the oracledb module for node.js. I tried using a for loop to use the iterator to go through each array in the next insert statement. I am new to node.js and have trouble understanding the callbacks which I think is just being called to early to release the connection. I am getting errors stating...

```
NJS-032: connection cannot be released because a database call is in progress
```

Here is the function code I am using.

```
  var doinsert2 = function (conn, cb) {
  //for(var i = 0; i<headers.length; i++)
  async.forEachOf(headers, function (value, key, callback) 
  {
      conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO " + db_extern_msg_prop + " VALUES ('" + unique_id + "','" + headers[key] + "',0,'" + values[key] + "')",
        //[unique_id, 'prop name test', 0, 'prop value test'],  // Bind values
        function(err, result)
        {
          if (err) {
            //return cb(err, conn);
            console.log("Error: " + err);
          } else {
            //console.log("SECOND INSERT : Rows inserted: " + result.rowsAffected);  // 1
            //return cb(null, conn);
          }
        });
        callback();
   },function (err) {
    //return cb(null, conn);    
   });

};

//used to order the functions to be processed. 
//This keeps the connection first, and the same unique id for both tables.
async.waterfall(
  [
    doconnect,
    doinsert1,
    doinsert2
  ],
  function (err, conn) {
    if (err) { console.error("In waterfall error cb: ", err, " "); }
    if (conn)
      dorelease(conn);
  });
```

All the records are being entered in fine but I want to better understand what I am missing. Also fairly new to stackoverflow so bear with me. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using async, which is good. Look into using async.eachSeries to iterate over your headers array instead of a for loop.

Comment: I looked into that but found that I couldn't pull the iterator out of that. I need to iterate over headers and values at the same time. I guess I could do eachSeries over the headers array and keep a separate iterator for values array.

Comment: I did find that maybe not eachSeries but maybe forEachOf may work and use the key in that to iterate over both. Good direction.

Comment: You're invoking the forEachOf callback outside of your conn.execute callback. Move that inside the conn.execute callback. That's really the whole point of async - it will do the next thing when you invoke the callback it passes in. But it relies on you to time that correctly.